# EditText not showing, typing text on Bottom sheet dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, bottom-sheet, chronometer, android-bottomsheetdialog

In bottom sheet dialog, we have some editext's . When typing those edittext typing can possible but **after typing the typing text is not showing** also not showing the edittext cursor.

When screen touch / scroll edittext is updating. I think its my design issue.Please take a look my xml.

*Also the chronometer stop when keyboard highlight. I'm also tried runOnUiThread, it's not working.*

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlBottomSheet"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <!-- Swipe down -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSwipeDown"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/swipe_down_to_cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llSwipeDown"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background_shape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".10"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/_dummy"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Chronometer
                    android:id="@+id/chTimer"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="11.05"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/str_hint_product_name">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/tvName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Test Product 1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp">

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="@string/str_hint_id">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/tvId"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Test Product 123"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                            android:textSize="16sp">

                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_25dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_code"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/iv_" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvImages"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/str_price"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center|start">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvPriceDot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18sp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etPrice"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvPriceDot"
                            android:importantForAutofill="no"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="1000"
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/rupee_symbol" />
                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center|start">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/str_quantity"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center|start">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvQDot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:text="@string/str_colon"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18sp" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/ibQRemove"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvQDot"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_background"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/ibremove"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvQCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ibQRemove"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_background"
                            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_3dp"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                            android:text="1" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/ibQAdd"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvQuantityCount"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_background"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/ib_quantity_add"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center|start">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center|start">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:text="@string/str_colon"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18sp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvDot"
                            android:importantForAutofill="no"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:singleLine="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorBottomSheetLineSeparator" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/str_cancel"
                        android:textAllCaps="false" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/send_button_corner_radius"
                        android:text="@string/str_send"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should try and make your layout file a little bit shorter. You can extract out some parts into another layout files and use include tag to use them in your main layout file.

Comment: Ok . thank u for you comment

Comment: Thanks @Ezio. i just tried as you said and also remove all weights . Now its working. But a little more lag found but i can show typing text on edittext.

Comment: When are you getting the lag?

Comment: when keyboard highlight to type.But we have total 3 edittext, the last one have the issue

Comment: @AbhijithKP have you get the solution

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will helps u..
Please upate this in Manifest..  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** Move upwards on click inside Edittext...

Comment: Other than Relative and Constraints, use Constraints for better performance..

Comment: in Manifest, already tried out but not working. Move upwards ???

Answer (score 1):

for my case it is because my android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Make sure in your AndroidManifest.xml, your hardware accelerated is true.

code :

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Answer (score 0):

Add before returning the view in the  *onCreateView* `dialog!!.window!!.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`

**following is the complete code on the method**

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.layout_password_dialog,
            container,
            false
        )
        dialog!!.window!!.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        return binding.root
    }
```

[look her for details](https://programmersought.com/article/89581467935/)